# Image overflows in columns for a split second

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code:

```
AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
  content: Container(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Image(
            image: correct
                ? AssetImage('assets/images/correct.png')
                : AssetImage('assets/images/wrong.png')),
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
        Text(message)
      ],
    ),
  ),
  actions: [
    okButton,
  ],
);
```

So, it almost works as expected. When I call the alert dialog, it appears correctly with the image and the text. But, for a split second, something overflows.

Here is the stack:

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> assertion was thrown during layout: A RenderFlex overflowed by 102
> pixels on the bottom.
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    Column
> file:///Users/path/to/file/blabla.dart:61:16
> : To inspect this widget in Flutter DevTools, visit:
> http://127.0.0.1:9100/#/inspector?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A55261%2FDahKsJWBhm4%3D%2F&inspectorRef=inspector-863
> The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical. The
> edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the
> rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually
> caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
>
> Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to
> force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space
> instead of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an
> error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot
> be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available
> space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it
> in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like
> a ListView.
>
> The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#117f5
> relayoutBoundary=up9 OVERFLOWING ...  parentData: offset=Offset(24.0,
> 20.0) (can use size) ...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=192.0, 0.0<=h<=120.0) ...  size: Size(192.0, 120.0) ...  direction: vertical ...  mainAxisAlignment: start ...  mainAxisSize: min ...
> crossAxisAlignment: center ...  verticalDirection: down
> ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤

Any idea what might cause this? Thx!

Comment: I hade about same issue, try set scaffolds `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to false maybe this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping your `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView` might fix the problem:

```
AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
  content: Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Image(
            image: correct
            ? AssetImage('assets/images/correct.png')
            : AssetImage('assets/images/wrong.png')),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
          Text(message)
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  actions: [
    okButton,
  ],
);
```